# C# datagridview вывод в двумерный массив

Tags: c#, datagridview

по заданию нужно файл Excel открыть в datagridview, потом эти данные запихнуть в массив и этот массив нужно вывести в новый datagridview. Excel документ я вывожу но вот как поместить в массив я не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте :

```
string[,] data = new string[dataGridView1.RowCount, dataGridView1.ColumnCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                data[i, j] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое